# Excel search number search in columns and rows

Tags: excel

Would like to find out how many times (rows) between matching numbers. So if F8 has a 14, when did the next 14 come up in the range of F9:J1000. So columns and rows to do a search in. So if the next 14 is at G11, the number would be 2.

Comment: Can you say what order you are searching in? Suppose there was a 14 in I9 - if you were searching across row 8 then across row 9 etc. this would come first, but if you were searching down column F then down column G etc., G11 would come first.

Comment: By row, starting at F9 to J9, then down to next row to only the first match and stop. So if 14 came up in F8, I only want to know the next time it came up and how many times between them. The issue seems to be that I can't find something that searches a range, only down a column. To bad =MATCH(I6,I7:I2040,0)-1 would not work for a range of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Using the exemple you provided wiht `lookup value = 14` and the `range = F9:J1000`, you could use an array formula (this means you need to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter on Excel 2013 and earlier) to find the distance between the first and the last match using this method.

#### Step 1:

Create an array that return the row of the match (if there is one) or zero.

```
=IF(F9:J1000=14,ROW(F9:J1000)-ROW($F$9)+1,0)
```

#### Step 2:

Calculate the smallest non-zero value in that array (from step 1) using this formula:

```
SMALL([The array],SUM(IF([The array]=0,1,0))+1)
```

#### Step 3:

You can find the maximum value in the array using the MAX function

```
MAX([The array])
```

#### Step 4:

Take the result from Step 3 minus the result from Step 2 and you got the difference in row between the highest and lowest match.